# How to get something in every 1 minute?

Tags: laravel-4

How I can get +50 resource in every 1 minute? My code is:

```
$r = DB::table('user_resources')->where('user_id', '=', 3)->first();

$time = time();

if ($time == 60) {
    return $r->Iron + 50;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

I know that this is absolutely incorrect but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: You'll need to run some kind of job to "do this every minute", but this should still be coupled with a refined discreet formula and delta - in case more than one period is skipped, or to delay calculations until requested, etc. (I actually recommend starting with *not* updating the database-stored resources every minute, but only when the discreet formula changes and/or when a computation is required.)

Comment: An example of a discreet formula is that for distance: `d = d0 + v * t` -> the final distance is the starting distance plus the velocity times the time.

Comment: Laravel (and web frameworks) are built for taking a user request and delivering a response. They aren't built to run "timers", but they can deliver the content that a separate timed task uses as a request point.

Answer (score 0):

First you got to fix your method into something like this:

```
public function addResource($n){
   $r = UserResources::where('user_id', '=', 3)->first();
   $r->Iron = $r->Iron+$n;
   $r->save();
   return $r->Iron;
}
```

Put the function at your route or controller if you use that. If this is a function that is suppose to be called by user, then create an AJAX call to the function from your view and iterate it every minute using the Javascript **setInterval()** method, else if this is suppose to be a backend service then you need to look into cron jobs.